# RedirectFromLoginPage() does not issue auth cookie for base domain

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on

Say I have 2 sites and want to implement SSO between them. They are hosted at *site1.localhost* and *site2.localhost*. From what I've read so far I only needed the following in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" domain=".localhost" path="/" />
    <machineKey .../>
</authentication>
```

However, the following call does not issue authentication cookie at all:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(InputEmail.Text, true);
```

If I remove `domain` attribute from `forms` element the cookie is perfectly issued for *site1.localhost* domain. What am I missing?

**p.s.**

Windows 7 x64, ASP.NET 4.0, integrated pipeline, no extra modules/handlers

**Update:**

The following call returns a cookie with proper domain set (*.localhost*):

```
HttpCookie httpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(InputEmail.Text, true )
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies need at least a 2 part domain name. If your sites were `site1.local.domain` & `site2.local.domain`, then you could issue a cookie for `.local.domain`. You cannot issue a cookie for .localhost

Comment: OMG, is it part of standard or specific implementation?

Comment: Standard part of cookie implementation in browsers. Otherwise you could add a cookie to .com